# Issues with Google Maps on Android Tutorial

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, build-error

Hey guys I've been trying to follow the tutorial that Google has on it's developers site on using Google Maps in Android. Needless to say I couldn't get the thing working and it had multiple errors. So I switched over to one from Youtube and that's giving me errors too. All I want to do is make the map come up. The errors that I couldn't work with is posted below. I really hope you guys can give me a clue as to what to do. Any help is much appreciated.

Also people note that every time I faced an issue I googled it and tried multiple 'fixes'. So any inconsistency in the code is brought about by that.

Errors:

> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':GoogleMapsDemoV2:compileDebug'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> C:\Users\Josebz\AndroidStudioProjects\GoogleMapsDemoV2Project\GoogleMapsDemoV2\src\main\java\com\example\googlemapsdemov2\MainActivity.java

Anyway here's all my code...

Main Activity

```
package com.example.googlemapsdemov2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemapsdemov2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemov2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemov2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAL5Xq8scMIHnWXITSOLN9QipVkri4A-lI"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemov2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_below="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'
}
```

Comment: Is your problem resolved .. ?

Comment: No not yet unfortunately

Comment: Also guys I'm getting the red squiggly lines on my MainActivity.java and it's telling me that "Cannot resolve symbol R". I looked online for a solution and I've made sure that there is no "import android.R" statement anywhere. From my understanding it could be caused due to errors in the layout file and the only other thing even close to an error I see is in the activity_main which is a warning about the rendering of the layouts. Could anyone execute this code and let me know if it works for you all?
@AndroidHacker

Answer (score 0):

Add following two lines before the MAP_KEY lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: are you sure the error what he/she posted is regarding yours answer..please explain it will be good learning for us as well

Comment: Nope. This is what I got instead : Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')
And that's weird because I'm pretty sure my GooglePlayServices is up to date

Answer (score 0):

1- First thing you must have insured that **GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES** are installed in your SDK or not.

for this open **Eclipse** ⇒ **Winhows** ⇒ **Androi SDK Manager** and check whether you already have downloaded?

2- Import it into your Eclipse

for this in Eclipse goto  **File** ⇒ **Import** ⇒ **Android** ⇒ **Existing Android Code Into Workspace**

and locate play services library project from

**android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib**

3- very important and main point for google map obtain a Google Map key

for that goto you Eclipse window tab > preferences > Android > Build and then copy your SHA-1 fingerprint.

then follow this [link](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect#project:364743935233%3aaccess) and then goto `Services` tab then search `Google Map API v2` and turn that **ON** and same as for `Goofle Play Android Dev API` then nevigate to `API ACCESS` tab and then **`Create new Android key..`**

Thanks

Comment: Given that he is getting a Gradle error, he is using Android Studio and not Eclipse. Therefore these directions do not apply.

Comment: What hannibal said. And either ways I've done all this. As you can see in my code I've included the key that Google has given me, for which I need to give them the SHA-1 that my computer generated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try using undermentioned under application section of manifest file ..

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

For Ex: Your manifest file ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemapsdemov2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemov2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemov2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
       <!--Your Google API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAL5Xq8scMIHnWXITSOLN9QipVkri4A-lI"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemov2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Secondly if you are testing same on lower versions of android then you need to use SupportMapFragment for same. Try like this ..

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_below="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Hope it sorts your problem and let me know if any concern ..

Comment: Tried the first solution you gave me, no changes. The second thing you told me ("map fragment") is already in my code so didn't have to change anything. These are the errors I'm currently getting...
'Gradle: Execution failed for task ':GoogleMapsDemoV2:processDebugResources'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':GoogleMapsDemoV2:processDebugResources''
and
'Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').'

Comment: Also I tried replacing the "@integer/google_play_services_version" part with "4132530" which is the version number. Then other errors pop up : [link](http://postimg.org/image/6qa3e274t/)